# How to find files with a specific pattern in the parent and child directory of my present working directory using a single command?

Tags: unix

How to find files with a specific pattern in the parent and child directory of my present working directory using a single command ?

Filename - test.txt, the file has the pattern "nslookup"

This file is present in 3 directories and they are /home, /home/1 and /home/1/2

I am currently at /home/1. I have tried below commands :

```
find ../ -type f -name "test.txt"
Output : 
../test.txt
../home/1/test.txt
../home/1/2/test.txt
```

I was able to find the files, hence I tried the below command :

```
$ find ../ -type f -exec grep "nslookup" {} \;
nslookup
nslookup
nslookup
```

This doesn't display the file names.

Command : 
    find . -type f -name "test.txt | xargs grep "nslookup' ==> gives me files in 
    pwd and child directories :

```
./1/test.txt:nslookup
./test.txt:nslookup
```

but when I try to search in the parent directory as shown below the results are erroneous :

```
find ../ -type f -name "test.txt" | xargs grep "nslookup

User@User-PC ~/test
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 User-PC 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
grep -r -l nslookup .. | grep test.txt
```